# LUIS Administation - "Include all predicted intent scores" resits to be turned OFF

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

In [LUIS.ai model Administration - publish section](https://www.luis.ai/applications/myAppId/versions/0.1/publish) I'm able to un-check the checkbox "Include all predicted intent scores". But whenever I perform the un-check it appears checked again after next load of the publish section or the whole model.

I also tried to perform "Publish" after I changed the setting but it didn't change the result.

**Is there any action I can do to "commit" change of "Include all predicted intent scores"?**

See UI screenshot for reference below.

---

[image]

---

@DFBerry thanks for your reply. To sum up: the checkbox value is not stored and performs following change in the endpoint url that the user may click at:

[image: Checked] -> [image]

versus:

[image: Unchecked] -> [image: Endpoijt url]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting is a convenience feature, in that the endpoint query url is constructed to include the correct name/value pair for the query string to include all intents. The client application, upstream of LUIS, needs to use the correct query string in order to ensure all intents are returned.

The settings has no practical impact on the LUIS portal because it only impacts the LUIS endpoint, which is separate from the portal.